# Вызов функции из фрагмента

Tags: java, android

Имею функцию:

```
  void readFile(String filew) throws MalformedURLException {
        String str;
        try {
            // открываем поток для чтения
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    getActivity().openFileInput(filew)));

            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ошибка чтения файла", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

Как ее же вызвать в другом фрагменте, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделать её статической и передавать туда ссылку на `Activity`:

```
public class MyUtils {

    public static void readFile(Activity activity, String filew) throws MalformedURLException {
        String str;
        try {
            // открываем поток для чтения
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    activity.openFileInput(filew)));

            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activity, "Ошибка чтения файла", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

}
```

Теперь из любого места программы можете вызвать `MyUtils.readFile(activity, "my_file_name");`.

Comment: В конце `getActivity()` осталась.

Comment: @post_zeew благодарю, поправил.